# Could not import flask_api.parsers.JSONParser for API setting DEFAULT_PARSERS

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pyinstaller

I have a flask project with multiple scripts ,templates and static folder.
I am using multiple flask modules like flask_pymongo,flask_cors and flask_api.
I'm trying to build executable windows program in .EXE format with PyInstaller.

I run the following command

```
 `python -m PyInstaller -F --add-data "templates;templates" --add-data "static;static"`
```

and it builds successfully.

```
62 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
62 INFO: Python: 3.6.0
62 INFO: Platform: Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0
64 INFO: wrote C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\__init__.spec
65 INFO: UPX is not available.
66 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\mohammadreza\\PycharmProjects\\nobina\\nobina_exe',
 'C:\\Users\\mohammadreza\\PycharmProjects\\nobina\\nobina_exe\\nobina']
66 INFO: checking Analysis
119 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
123 INFO: checking PYZ
152 INFO: checking PKG
158 INFO: Building because toc changed
159 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
2676 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
2711 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
2711 INFO: checking EXE
2719 INFO: Building because toc changed
2719 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
2720 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\dist\__init__.exe
3310 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

But when i try to run my program in dist folder i get the following error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\mohammadreza>cd C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe
\nobina\dist

C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\dist>__init__.exe

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\settings.py", line 25, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importl
ib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_api.parsers'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\__init__.
py", line 22, in <module>
    from nobina.installation import install
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\__init__.
py", line 22, in <module>
    from nobina.installation import install
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\installat
ion.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nobina.Models.Admin import Admin
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\Models\Ad
min.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nobina.Models.Base import BaseModel, AggregateQuery
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\Models\Ba
se.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nobina.utility import load_class, dump_class
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\nobina\utility.p
y", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_api import status
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_api.app import FlaskAPI
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_api.request import APIRequest
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\request.py", line 13, in <module>
    class APIRequest(Request):
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\request.py", line 14, in APIRequest
    parser_classes = default_settings.DEFAULT_PARSERS
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\settings.py", line 45, in DEFAULT_PARSERS
    return perform_imports(val, 'DEFAULT_PARSERS')
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\settings.py", line 13, in perform_imports
    return [perform_imports(item, setting_name) for item in val]
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\settings.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    return [perform_imports(item, setting_name) for item in val]
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\settings.py", line 11, in perform_imports
    return import_from_string(val, setting_name)
  File "C:\Users\mohammadreza\PycharmProjects\nobina\nobina_exe\venv\lib\site-pa
ckages\flask_api\settings.py", line 30, in import_from_string
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Could not import 'flask_api.parsers.JSONParser' for API setting 'DE
FAULT_PARSERS'. No module named 'flask_api.parsers'.
[6808] Failed to execute script __init__
```

I tried downgrading flask-api to v1.0 and it didn't work out either.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `hidden-import=flask_api.parsers` to your build command?

Comment: i added  `--hidden-import=flask_api.parsers` &  `--hidden-import=flask_api.renderers` and it works ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i added `--hidden-import=flask_api.parsers` & `--hidden-import=flask_api.renderers` and it works